# Working with the html5 audio object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

Revised to include minimal code that still demonstrates problem.
My code:

```
 <div class="caster-player">
    <div class="caster-player__controls">
      <progress class="caster-player__progress" value="0"></progress>
      <span class="caster-player__currenttime caster-player__time">00:00:00</span>
      <span class="caster-player__duration caster-player__time">00:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <audio src="https://bythecoverpodcast.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/01-No-Money.mp3"></audio>
<p>"No Money" from No Money by Galantis.</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {
    var audioObj = $('audio');
    var audioEl = audioObj[0];
    var progress = $('.caster-player__progress');
    var duration = $('.caster-player__duration');

    function toHHMMSS( totalsecs ) {
        var sec_num = parseInt(totalsecs, 10);
        var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

        if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours; }
        if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
        if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}

        var time = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
        return time;
    }    

    console.log(audioObj)
    audioObj.on('loadedmetadata', function(){
        progress.attr('max', Math.floor(audioEl.duration));
        duration.text(toHHMMSS(audioEl.duration));
      });

})
</script>
```

I am attempting to create a simple audio player for a podcasting website. 
for the most part I have everything working how I want it except for one thing. I am using a progress element to show the progress of the audio track and need to dynamically set the max attribute for it to work.

According to documentation on the audio element there are several events available to create an event handler for this purpose. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onloadedmetadata.asp 
Based on this it looks like onLoadedMetaData is the ticket, but the following event handler never runs

```
audioObj.on('loadedmetadata', function(){
  progress.attr('max', Math.floor(audioEl.duration));
  duration.text(toHHMMSS(audioEl.duration));
});
```

I have a feeling that because I have this code wrapped in a 'document.ready()' that I am actually missing the event.
Overall I am quite confused and any guidance you have to offer on this subject will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
Joeslost

Comment: You are required to post your code here within your question, not a codepen! [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right -- **'loadedmetadata'** is what you want. But your **audioEl.on()** handler isn't running because **audioEl** is no longer wrapped as a jQuery object:

```
// Creates an <audio> DIV and wraps it as a jQuery object.
var audioObj = $('audio');

// Takes the inner <audio> element out of the jQuery object.
var audioEl = audioObj[0];
```

Once it's out of the jQuery wrapping (which you did so you could directly get at **.play()**), it no longer has the convenient jQuery event-handler methods like **.on()**.

I just used the original `audioObj` (which is already wrapped) and it worked great with 'loadedmetadata':

```
// Set the Max Attribute of the progress bar
audioObj.on('loadedmetadata', function(){
    progress.attr('max', Math.floor(audioEl.duration));
    duration.text(toHHMMSS(audioEl.duration));
});
```

**One note:** to avoid confusion like this for myself, I (and a lot of other people I know & work with) like to prefix variable names for jQuery-wrapped elements with a `$` to indicate that the var is already wrapped:

```
var $audioEl = $('audio');
var audioEl = $audioEl[0];
```

That way it's pretty clear from then on out.

Comment: Reagan, if you don't include jquery in snippet, the snippet when run will show an error. If you want you can just include indented code to illustrate changes

Comment: @Rob the piece of advice is applicable to all answers, not solely the answer to this question, or any future questions the answerer may ask

Comment: Sorry, figured that out after posting. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Reagan, I tried my listener on $(audioEl) but that did not fire either. I would have thought that $(audioEl) and my audioObj would be the same jquery object, but when loged to the console they are slightly different, same data different context. Pretty interesting but not the solution.

Comment: Err scratch that, It looks like that does work, but will not rerun if the window is refreshed which fooled me. I guess the audio element is only loaded once So I will need to store audioEl.duration in the cache some how. Thanks!